# How to get analytics to link ecommerce to adwords campaigns

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads, conversions

I've been busy setting up analytics and adwords campaigns for a webshop I'm managing.
In Analytics I have enabled ecommerce and this seems to work fine, meaning the when I go to `Conversions > Ecommerce` in analytics, I can see transactions and their amounts fine.

In my analytics account, which I've linked to my adwords account, I can see my adwords campaigns, however, when I go to `Aquisition > AdWords > Campaigns`, and then select `Ecommerce` from the conversions drop down, I see no conversions at all for any of my AdWords campaigns. In fact I tried searching for one of my keyboards, Clicked on my add (which was a google shopping ad, so direct link to product page), and made a transaction on my webshop. This test transaction is visible in my general Ecommerce overview, however when I go to the campaign for which I clicked the ad, I still see '0' in the conversion column.

Clicks for the mentioned campaigns are counted just fine, I just don't seem to find out how to get analytics to link the conversions to ecommerce transactions.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement the Ecommerce tracking in your checkout.php(the last step of you purchasing line, when the customer clicks on pay) file and Forward the variables like Price/buyer/Transaction ID to Google analytics.

You may take look in the Google references
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034306?hl=en
and
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I think the ecommerce tracking in the checkout page is fine, since I'm seeing all my transactions in the `Conversions > Ecommerce` screen of analytics. The problem is that these transactions are not linked to AdWords campaigns, since all my campaigns show 0 conversions

Comment: I had a second look, please check your implementation with the following links https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1722054?hl=en http://www.wordstream.com/blog/ws/2013/08/13/adwords-conversion-tracking-guide  https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1722021?hl=en  https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1722022?hl=en

Comment: The last 2 links you provided are for the tracking in AdWords, which I have working fine. I want to get the conversion tracking working in analytics, when I look at my adwords campaigns in analytics, I get 0 conversions all the time...

Answer (score 1):

Try to go to Conversions -> Attribution. Above the tab click on AdWords under the label *Type*. Then change the model to something else.

If AdWords is counted as an *assist conversions* and not a *last click conversion*, there's some problem  about your website. It could be:

- 302 redirects (fix them)
- http or https redirects (fix them)
- your payment gateway (add your payment gateway URL address to Referral Exclusion, get your people come back to your website after the payment, )

In these cases your traffic is converted to *direct traffic*. If you fix them, you should be able to track properly AdWords campaigns.

If AdWords isn't present, the problem is your Google Analytics implementation.